# Sorting an array of pointers to a struct on the basis of a struct member - best possible option?

Tags: c

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct details clientDetails;
struct details 
{
    int socket;  
    char* port;
    char* IP;
    char* hostName;
    int msgSentCount;
    int msgRecvCount;
    char* status;
    char* bufferMsg;
    char* blockedUser[4];
    int blockedCount;   
};
```

And I have the following array of pointers to the struct:

`clientDetails* allClients[4];`

What would be the best possible way to keep the array sorted by the `port` number of the struct?

The implementation required would be as follows:

`sortByPort(allClients)` -> passes a reference to the array and sorts it so that if I print the values of `allClients` after this function call, I will have it sorted by the `port` number.

Comment: You could have a look at the [`qsort()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) function.

Comment: Could you please list the options that you investigated so far? And also what's preventing you from picking one?

Comment: I have just implemented bubble sort based on the port number, by swapping cells of the array (struct as a whole). It seems to work. But I was kind of trying to find out better options.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on which sorting algorithm suits best in your application. It could be, quick sort, merge sort, or a simple selection sort.
As your example the length of the array is just 4, I've made an example with selection sort:

```
clientDetails * sortByPort(clientDetails *pClients, size_t len)
{
   size_t i, k;

   for (i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i) {
      size_t k = i;

      for (j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) {
         if (atoi(pClients[j].port) < atoi(pClients[k].port)) {
            k = j;
         }
      }

      clientDetails *tmp = pClients[k];
      pClients[k] = pClients[i];
      pClients[i] = tmp;
   }

   return pClients;
}
```

You can use `strtol` instead of `atoi` if the port is greater than an `int` value.